# Modifying the copy coords plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt4

I want to modify the copy_coords plugin such that when I click on it, It should open a dialog box and ask for a file name and address. After this it should store all the points I click on into that file. As of now, I have modified the code such that it will save it in a CSV file which is predetermined, so rather than saving it in a predetermined file, it is better to store it in a file determined by the user.

I have added these few lines at the end of the original code:

```
xx=str(point.x())
yy=str(point.y())
clipboard= QApplication.clipboard()
clipboard.setText(str(xx)+","+str(yy)) #This is the original part of the code
#these are the lines i have added
fd=open("XYZ.csv","a")
fd.write(str(xx)+","+str(yy)+"\n")
fd.close
```

So I need help on getting the input dialog for getting the filename and address. Please note, I am new to Python.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a file dialog example using the QFileDialog object which gets the selected .csv filename path:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QFileDialog

# put this statment below at the bottom of the def run(self): function
fileNamePath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Choose csv file", 'C:/Temp', '*.csv')
```

This should open a file dialog each time you click on the plugin button.

Comment: getopenfilename is useful if the file was previously created, wouldn't getsavefile be a better option?

Comment: @SunnyNaik, getsavefile will just save it, I thought you wanted to open it and append to it?  getOpenFileName will get you the path which you may then open it and append values to it.

Comment: Yes, but also I should be able to create the file if it does not exist.